# How to parse one STIX pattern to generate multi-patterns for OR logic?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a STIX pattern as below:

```
stix_ptn_and_or_case2 = '''[(x:x.x = 'A' OR x:x.x = 'B' ) AND ( x:x.x = 'C' OR x:x.x = 'D' )]'''
```

The pattern's logic is `(A OR B) AND (C OR D)`

The pattern can be parsed to an expression tree by dendrol (python lib) as below

[image]

The logic of  `(A OR B) AND (C OR D)` can be separated to 4 small and `AND only logic` below

- A `AND` C
- A `AND` D
- B `AND` C
- B `AND` D

I want to parse the expression tree to get the 4 `AND only logic`

[image]

So I written the python code as below. The python lib dendrol can convert STIX pattern to expression tree.

```
import os, sys, datetime, copy
from dendrol import Pattern

stix_ptn_and_or_case2 = '''[(x:x.x = 'A' OR x:x.x = 'B' ) AND ( x:x.x = 'C' OR x:x.x = 'D' )]'''

ptn = Pattern(stix_ptn_and_or_case2)
pdt = ptn.to_dict_tree()
obj = pdt['pattern']
all_ptn_element_list = []

# the recursion function for expression tree to and-only logic
def ptnct(obj, ptn_element_list):
    if('observation' in obj or 'expression' in obj):
        if('observation' in obj):
            join = obj['observation']['join']
            expressions  = obj['observation']['expressions']
        else:
            join = obj['expression']['join']
            expressions  = obj['expression']['expressions']
        if(join=='AND' or join==None):
            for exp in expressions:
                p = ptnct(exp, ptn_element_list)
                if(p!=None):
                    ptn_element_list.append(p)
            if(len(ptn_element_list)==len(expressions)):# all and 
                all_ptn_element_list.append(ptn_element_list)
        elif(join=='OR'):
            for exp in expressions:
                p = ptnct(exp, ptn_element_list)
                tmp = copy.deepcopy( ptn_element_list )
                tmp.append(p)
                all_ptn_element_list.append(tmp)                    

    elif('comparison' in obj):
        exp = obj
        tag = '{0}:{1}.{2}'.format(exp['comparison']['object'], exp['comparison']['path'][0], exp['comparison']['path'][1])
        value = exp['comparison']['value']
        return value

x=ptnct(obj, [])
print(all_ptn_element_list)
```

The output of the code is

```
[[u'A'], [u'B'], [u'C'], [u'D']]
```

But the desired output is

```
[[u'A', u'C'], [u'A', u'D'], [u'B', u'C'], [u'B', u'D']]
```

Actually the code works for most of the cases, but not this one.

Any suggestion for parsing an AND-OR logic expression tree to AND-only expressions(patterns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ever-handy `itertools.product` and `itertools.chain`, we can convert the tree of disjunct expressions into a list of all possible conjunct expressions

```
from itertools import product, chain

from dendrol import Pattern


def extract_atomic_chunks(root):
    container = root.get('observation') or root.get('expression')
    comparison = root.get('comparison')

    if container:
        join = container['join']
        expressions = container['expressions']

        if join == 'OR':
            # Return all possibilities under this node
            return chain(
                extract_atomic_chunks(expression)
                for expression in expressions
            )

        elif join == 'AND':
            # Generate all possible N-tuples, where N=len(expressions) 
            groups = [
                extract_atomic_chunks(expression)
                for expression in expressions
            ]
            return product(*groups)

    elif comparison:
        return comparison['value']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stix_expr = "[(x:x.x = 'A' OR x:x.x = 'B') AND (x:x.x = 'C' OR x:x.x = 'D')]"

    pattern = Pattern(stix_expr)
    tree = pattern.to_dict_tree()
    root = tree['pattern']

    print(list(extract_atomic_chunks(root)))
```

I think that gets you where you want

```
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D')]
```